# How to compare two unreadable file and get difference in java?

Tags: java

I have two files exported from one software which have same content while exporting but once it is exported and when i compare two files , it shows difference. In fact, size of both files are same.

So my intension is to identify what is that added while exports but the problem is that file is having different extension.

I tried using Files.reallAllBytes() and FileUtils.contentEquals() which in fact works and says there is difference but i can't identify what is that difference.

So is there any way we can write algorithm in java and find what is the difference ? Actually that file is of Graphics having ".gfx" extension.

There is something which software add any text while export.

Please help me

Comment: Difference in terms of?

Comment: If you can't interpret the content of those files you can only try to find different bytes although finding the correct differences might be hard. Once you have those bytes, how would you interpret those? - I hope you can see that without being able to interpret/parse the file it's next to impossible to get any meaningful information.

Comment: One thing you could try though: most file formats use some sort of magic bytes which you can use to at least guess the format independent of the extension - for the case that the different extension mean that one is wrong. Once you know the format you should be able to find/write a parser to convert the data into a comparable form.

Comment: Both are of same extension "gfx" and have same content before i export. Even after export both files are of same size. GFX is of FactoryTalk View Studio's Interface Design file. This software has inbuilt feature to convert it to .xml but i don't want to go with this step.

Comment: as already said, without a proper interpretation of differing bytes, you will not gain much.
cold guessing: somewhere in the file, a creation timestamp is written, which will differ on every save, even if the rest of the content is the same